# Solve simultaneous equations using Ryacas package (OldSolve) in R

Tags: r, solver, equation-solving, simultaneous

I am trying to solve a system of 3 equations using Ryacas package in R.

```
library(Ryacas)
 yacas("OldSolve({(f*Reg/(k + Reg)) - r*BB - ab * BB - a1*f1*BB*AA*P - fp*BB*P==0,(ab * BB + a1*f1*BB*AA*P)/e1 - m1 * AA == 0, (fp * BB * P)/ep - f1*AA*P - mp * P ==0 },{BB,AA,P})")
```

But I get the following answer in R

```
expression(list(list(BB == BB, AA == (f * Reg/(k + Reg) - r * 
    BB - ab * BB - fp * BB * P)/(P * (a1 * f1 * BB)), P == P)))
```

However, I'm supposed to get the [following answer](https://rextester.com/QLD4907) if I solve on other software (Its too big to write it out on stackoverflow)

Basically of the form

```
{BB -> some value, AA -> some value, P-> 0}, {BB -> some value, AA -> some value, P-> some value}, 
{BB -> some value, AA -> some value, P-> some value}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to fully prove it, but it's most likely that `OldSolve` is too weak for this system.

A couple of important points from the [manual](http://yacas.sourceforge.net/ref.book.pdf):

> This command **tries** to solve one or more equations.

Hence, no guarantees.

> Note that only **one** solution is found and returned.

Meaning that there surely is no way to get all three solutions that you mentioned.

> Again, **at most a single** solution is returned.

The fact that you got `BB == BB` and `P == P` means infinitely many solutions, so possibly we can see it as an evidence of failure to solve the system.

> Multiple equations are solved **recursively**: firstly, an equation is
>   sought in which **one of the variables occurs exactly once**; then this
>   equation is solved with SuchThat; and finally the solution is
>   **substituted in the other equations** by Eliminate decreasing the number
>   of equations by one. This suffices for all linear equations and a
>   **large group** of simple nonlinear equations

So, this kind of explains why `OldSolve` may fail in your system. First, it's nonlinear, giving no guarantees. Second, each of the variables appears in each of the equations 1-4 times. If I understand the algorithm correctly, after solving one equation (w.r.t. `AA`, say) and substituting the solution to the other two - we are done. That's because then both `BB` and `P` appear in both of the remaining equations more than once (and, as a result, `OldSolve` fails to solve any of them). You can also try to switch the order of the equations; you will see that then a different variable gets solved for.